# Connecting to work network from home

Tags: remote, rdp, remmina

I have to work from home and need to connect to my work network.

I have been given a RDP shortcut from work IT and need to connect to it. I have downloaded Remmina and few other RDPs apps but I cannot seem to get it to work. Remmina works fine in the local network but not from home. I tried it on my wifes iPad on a Microsoft Remote App and it works fine.

Does any one know if there is any RDP app which will allow this please?
Thank you

Comment: What errors are you seeing? Can you give more details? There is very little anyone can do without details.

Comment: Did you connect to your work network first, for example using a VPN or a SSH tunnel? RDP alone cannot work from home if your work network is not accessible.